# Convert MFC message handler to VCL message handler

Tags: c++, mfc, c++builder, messaging, vcl

I am adopting some code from a MFC application into a C++Builder VCL application. This code is dealing with a live Camera.

The issue is how to catch windows messages regarding the camera. In the MFC code, the following message map is defined:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Cuc480LiveDlg, CDialog)
 ... //Code omitted

   ON_MESSAGE(IS_UC480_MESSAGE, OnUSBCameraMessage)

 ... //Code omitted
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

where the 'handling' function is:

```
LRESULT Cuc480LiveDlg::OnUSBCameraMessage( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch ( wParam )
    {
        case IS_DEVICE_REMOVED:
            Beep( 400, 50 );
            break;

        case IS_DEVICE_RECONNECTED:
            Beep( 400, 50 );
            break;

        case IS_FRAME:
            if(m_pcImageMemory != NULL)
                m_camera.RenderBitmap(m_lMemoryId, m_hDisplay,     IS_RENDER_FIT_TO_WINDOW);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How do I translate the above to work in a VCL application's message handling?

Creating the following Form handler

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
      MESSAGE_HANDLER(IS_UC480_MESSAGE, unsigned int, OnUSBCameraMessage);
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TForm)
```

and function

```
LRESULT TMainForm::OnUSBCameraMessage( WPARAM wParam)//, LPARAM lParam )
{
switch ( wParam )
{
    case IS_DEVICE_REMOVED:
        Beep( 400, 50 );
        break;

    case IS_DEVICE_RECONNECTED:
        Beep( 400, 50 );
        break;

    case IS_FRAME:
        if(mImageMemory != NULL)
            mCamera.RenderBitmap(mMemoryId, mDisplayHandle, IS_RENDER_FIT_TO_WINDOW);
        break;

    case 1280:
        if(mImageMemory != NULL)
        {
            mCamera.RenderBitmap(mMemoryId, mDisplayHandle, IS_RENDER_FIT_TO_WINDOW);
        }
        else
        {
            Log(lError) << "No Image memory";
        }
        break;

}

//  Log(lDebug) << "Got message: "<<wParam;
return 0;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work properly. The IS_UC480_MESSAGE is caught, but the message value (wParam) is always the same (1280).

Does anyone know how to translate the MFC code to VCL?

This question is about how to translate the MFC code to VCL code, not how to send/receive messages in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Builder XE, Passing and handling user-defined messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136957/c-builder-xe-passing-and-handling-user-defined-messages). This still works the same. Note that messages are handled differently than in MFC. Handlers usually get passed a `TMessage*` (IIRC) which contains the various parameters (WPARAM, LPARAM, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The Rudy V. article helped me fix the above code. In short, changing the OnUSBCameraMessage to take a TMessage, and using the wparam of that object worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Look at [Using the Windows API Messaging Solution](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Windows_API_Messaging_Solution). Using `MESSAGE_HANDLER` will work, but generally it is better to override the virtual `WndProc()` method instead. `MESSAGE_HANDLER` is just a fancy macro for overriding the virtual `Dispatch()` method, which gets called by the base `WndProc()` method for unhandled messages. So it takes longer for a message to reach `Dispatch()` than to reach an overridden `WndProc()`...

Comment: ... Also, in the interest of encapsulation, overriding `WndProc()` lets you hide from outside code which messages you process, whereas using a `MESSAGE_HANDLER` announces it out and clear in the Form's header file. Which also means if you make any changes to the list of messages you process, your Form's header file changes, which means any code that uses the Form's header has to be recompiled. Overriding `WndProc()` does not cause that same behavior (unless you override it inline in the header, which is not a good idea).

Comment: Great deep info. For the case of live camera messages it may make sense to make it as fast as possible, so we may over ride WndProc() instead, as you suggest.