# Can a secondary TForm notify the MainForm when it is closing?

Tags: windows, c++builder, vcl, rad-studio

I am using RAD Studio 10 working on a Windows VCL application. I have two Forms, `Form1` (the MainForm in `Unit1.cpp`) and a secondary `Form2` (in `Unit2.cpp`). I managed to embed `Form2` inside of `Form1`. This is just a setup to illustrate the problem. My real project has multiple Forms.

When closing `Form2`, the VCL triggers the `Form2::OnClose()` event. Knowing that `Form2` was created dynamically in `Form1` (the MainForm), is there a `Form1` event that will fire upon `Form2` being closed? Or something inside `Form1` to know that `Form2` is closing?

- I was thinking of customizing an event handler like `OnChildFormClose` but I couldn't make it.
- I tried to wrap the code that I wanted to execute on `Form1` when `Form2` is closed in a public function and call it in the `Form2::OnClose()` event, and it worked to some extent, but it is not a good approach if you have multiple Forms.

```cpp
//FROM THE unit1.cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit2.h"
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
TForm2 *form2 = new TForm2(this);
form2->ManualDock(container);
form2->Show();
}
```

```cpp
//FROM unit2.cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit2.h"
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Close();
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can I implement something like an `OtherFormsonClose(*Sender)` event in `Form1` with a `Sender` that we can dynamically cast to check if it is `Form2`, or maybe I am wrong? I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a common event handler of type `TCloseEvent`, e.g. `OtherFormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action);` in the main form:

```
private:    // User declarations
   void __fastcall TForm1::OtherFormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action);
```

implementation

```
void __fastcall TForm1::OtherFormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
  Action = caFree;
  TForm2 *f2 = dynamic_cast<TForm2 *>(Sender);
  if (f2) {
  ShowMessage(String("Form2 closing")); //Do stuff
  }

}
```

(or use `Sender` to inspect which form)

Then when you create other forms in code, e.g. `Form2`, you assign

```
  TForm2 *form2 = new TForm2(this);
  form2->OnClose = OtherFormClose;
  // etc
```

Comment: Thanks This is Good, With your solution there's no more trouble with regards to conflicting  messages. Perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found something interesting after reading [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20755769/How-to-send-and-receive-message-between-2-forms-in-an-application.html), [this](http://www.bcbjournal.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1841), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136957/c-builder-xe-passing-and-handling-user-defined-messages), and [this](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol1/9706/Incorporate_custom_message-handling_in_your_applications.htm).

So basically, a VCL Delphi/C++Builder application uses Windows Form Messages for comunication, and we can override the virtual function `WndProc` to catch a specific message, but it must be some unique message because VCL uses a lot of messages and if you don't tread carefully things might blow up; This will translate to a custom event handler on the main form.

So what I did is :

- Passed the MainForm handle to Form2 in the constructor to be saved on a Form2 private var and to be used only for the messaging.
- Generate a specific ID that I use to tag the message to make it stand out
- overriding the `WndProc` and filtering messages with a specific ID so we know that Form2 is closing.

Test it and it worked, maybe someone have a better idea.

```cpp
//From unit2.h---------------------------------------------------------
class TForm2 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action);
private:    // User declarations
    HWND mfhandle;
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm2(TComponent* Owner, HWND mainformhandle);

};
```

```cpp
//From unit2.cpp---------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)

#pragma resource "*.dfm"

TForm2 *Form2;
const UINT uiMyCopyDataID = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("MyCopyDataID"));

__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner,HWND mainformhandle)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
mfhandle = mainformhandle;
}

void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Close();
}

void __fastcall TForm2::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
//Notify the mainForm and say Hey I am closing now
PostMessage(mfhandle, uiMyCopyDataID, 0, 0);
}
```

```cpp
//From unit1.h---------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
TPanel *container;
void __fastcall FormCreate(TObject *Sender);
void __fastcall FormUnDock(TObject *Sender, TControl *Client, TWinControl *NewTarget,
      bool &Allow);
private:    // User declarations
protected:
void __fastcall TForm1::WndProc(TMessage &Message);  //Added THIS
public:     // User declarations
__fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
```

```
//From unit1.cpp-------------------------------------------------------
const UINT uiMyCopyDataID = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("MyCopyDataID"));

void __fastcall TForm1::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == uiMyCopyDataID)
    {
    //Do SomeThing here
    ShowMessage("Form2 is closing");

    }

    TForm::WndProc(Message);
}
```

Ok, So far it works and custom messages MUST be in the WM_USER (0x0400 - 0x7FFF) range.

Comment: Using window messages is way overkill for this situation.

Comment: Hi Remy Lebeau I totally agree, I was nicely surprised by Tom Brunberg response.